# JetBrains Writerside deploy to GitHub pages

Tags: github-actions, github-pages, jetbrains-ide

I'm in some trouble right now. I used the official JetBrains Writerside documentation for deployment.

- I maintain my Writerside documents and other information in a private repository.
- Want to publish to my pages repository on GitHub.
- Errors are now reported when executing actions in private repositories.

When you execute steps Setup Pages, use `actions/configure-pages@v3`

Error message:

> Error:  Get Pages site failed. Please verify that the repository has Pages enabled and configured to build using GitHub Actions,  or consider exploring the `enablement` parameter for this action.
> Error: HttpError: Not Found

Does anyone know how to deal with this, this is the use of docker deployment.

Here is my yml configuration:

```yaml
name: writeside build

on:
# If specified, the workflow will be triggered automatically once you push to the `main` branch.
# Replace `main` with your branch’s name
push:
branches: ["master"]
# Specify to run a workflow manually from the Actions tab on GitHub
#workflow_dispatch:

# Gives the workflow permissions to clone the repo and create a page deployment
permissions:
contents: read
id-token: write
pages: write

env:
# Name of module and id separated by a slash
INSTANCE: Writerside/hi
# Replace HI with the ID of the instance in capital letters
ARTIFACT: webHelpHI2-all.zip
# Writerside docker image version
DOCKER_VERSION: 232.10275
# Add the variable below to upload Algolia indexes
# Replace HI with the ID of the instance in capital letters
ALGOLIA_ARTIFACT: algolia-indexes-HI.zip
ALGOLIA_APP_NAME: xxxxxx
ALGOLIA_INDEX_NAME: xxx
ALGOLIA_KEY: ${{ secrets.ALGOLIA_KEY }}
CONFIG_JSON_PRODUCT: HI
CONFIG_JSON_VERSION: 1.0

jobs:
build:
runs-on: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- name: Checkout repository
uses: actions/checkout@v3

- name: Build Writerside docs using Docker
uses: JetBrains/writerside-github-action@v4
with:
instance: ${{ env.INSTANCE }}
artifact: ${{ env.ARTIFACT }}
docker-version: ${{ env.DOCKER_VERSION }}

- name: Upload documentation
uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
with:
name: docs
path: |
artifacts/${{ env.ARTIFACT }}
artifacts/report.json
retention-days: 7

# Add the step below to upload Algolia indexes
- name: Upload algolia-indexes
uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
with:
name: algolia-indexes
path: artifacts/${{ env.ALGOLIA_ARTIFACT }}
retention-days: 7

# Add the job below and artifacts/report.json on Upload documentation step above if you want to fail the build when  documentation contains errors
test:
# Requires build job results
needs: build
runs-on: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- name: Download artifacts
uses: actions/download-artifact@v1
with:
name: docs
path: artifacts

- name: Test documentation
uses: JetBrains/writerside-checker-action@v1
with:
instance: ${{ env.INSTANCE }}

publish-indexes:
# Requires the build-job results
needs: build
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
container:
Image: registry. Jetbrains. Team/p/writerside/builder/algolia - publisher: 2.0.32-2

steps:
- name: Download artifact
uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
with:
name: algolia-indexes
- name: Unzip artifact
run: |
unzip -O UTF-8 -qq ${{ env.ALGOLIA_ARTIFACT }} -d algolia-indexes
env "algolia-key=${{env.ALGOLIA_KEY}}" java -jar /opt/builder/help-publication-agent.jar \
update-index \
--application-name ${{env.ALGOLIA_APP_NAME}} \
--index-name ${{env.ALGOLIA_INDEX_NAME}} \
--product ${{env.CONFIG_JSON_PRODUCT}} \
--version ${{env.CONFIG_JSON_VERSION}} \
--index-directory algolia-indexes/ \
2&gt; &1 | tee algolia-update-index-log.txt

deploy:
environment:
name: github-pages
url: ${{ steps.deployment.outputs.page_url }}
# Requires the build job results
needs: test
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
steps:
- name: Download artifact
uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
with:
name: docs

- name: Unzip artifact
run: unzip -O UTF-8 -qq ${{ env.ARTIFACT }} -d dir

- name: Setup Pages
uses: actions/configure-pages@v3

- name: Upload artifact
uses: actions/upload-pages-artifact@v1
with:
path: dir

- name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
id: deployment
uses: actions/deploy-pages@v1
```

I've tried other methods, but nothing seems to work.

So, I wish I could build my Writerside Docker image in my private repository and then publish it to my public pages repository.

Comment: I use the WS github actions for my public repo. You might find some clues here: https://github.com/SteveDunn/Vogen/blob/main/.github/workflows/deploy.yaml#L35